# Understanding logic behind Sparse Autoencoders

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, autoencoder

I am currently going through a **sparse autoencoder.** What I understood is we don't need all hidden units to fire for every input rather **some specific hidden units** depending on the type of input. For this we are adding a **sparse regularization term** to the loss function. But I am unable to get how adding this regularization term to loss function helps us in stopping certain hidden units to fire up?[sparse autoencoder](https://www.quora.com/Why-are-sparse-autoencoders-sparse)

Answer (score 0):

> But I am unable to get how adding this regularization term to loss function helps us in stopping certain hidden units to fire up?

Because the this regularization term will precisely penalize excessive activations. As opposed to conventional regularization, in which re penalize  the weights through the `L1` or `L2` norms, in this case we penalize the output of the activation functions by a scale factor. This method ensures only a subset of neurons in a hidden layer are activated  for specific inputs, which overall yields better results, since you end up with more "specialized" neurons, that only fire for specific inputs, rather than all.

So just think of it in the way conventional regularization works. By adding a regularization term in the loss function in a Lasso regression, we are penalizing high coefficients through the `L1` norm, and enforcing that when minimized, the loss function will yield smaller weights. Well in sparse regularization we are instead shrinking the *activation vectors* and reducing the subset of neurons that will fire for each input.